# indexOf to some() javaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert the function below to use the .some() method but I don't understand how this works. I've aready read the MDN documentation.
Can anyone help me?

```
function guessRepeatValidate(userGuess) {
    let passed = true;
    if (guessArchive.indexOf(userGuess) > -1) {
        passed = false;
    }
    return passed;

}
```

Comment: `.some` is not appropriate here. `guessRepeatValidate = guess => !guessArchive.includes(guess)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know, but .som() is a requirement. It MUST replace the indexOf.

Comment: Per @CertainPerformance some() performs an operation/evaluation that you pass in. Where in includes() is taking a value (which is what you need).

Comment: It's *possible* to use `.some` here, it's just *really weird*

Comment: @CertainPerformance Homework. It's almost always homework :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to convert.

```js
let guessArchive = ['test', 'some'];

function guessRepeatValidate(userGuess) {
    return !guessArchive.some(i => i===userGuess);
}

console.log(guessRepeatValidate('test'));

console.log(guessRepeatValidate('blah'));
```

Comment: Great @Bibberty, this works beautifully. And I would never use an arrow function to it. It's a great example on how to apply this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const guessRepeatValidate = (userGuess, guessArchive) => !guessArchive.some(i => i === userGuess);

const guessArchive = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

console.log(guessRepeatValidate('one', guessArchive));

console.log(guessRepeatValidate('four', guessArchive));
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted practice for this kind of problem would be using `includes`, however, if you really want to use `some`:

```
function guessRepeatValidate(userGuess) {
    return !guessArchive.some(e => e == userGuess);
}
```